# Dereferencing a character pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
char *str = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
*str ="Hello"; // or pass it any string
```

Now I want to pass `str` in the function:

sys_open(const char * filename, int flags, int mode)

When I use a char array as the second parameter, it works, but using the pointer whose value was copied over does not work.

I can achieve what I want with a char array, but why can't I do the same with a pointer?

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile cleanly.  Do you not get a warning?  As an editorial note, `sizeof(char)` is `1`, so you don't need to bother typing the extra characters.

Comment: The second line is an invalid cast from `const char*` to `char`.

Comment: I pass sys_open(infileName, "0_RDWR", 00700); if I were to put a string literal lile "a.txt" instead of infileName, it would work. My pointer does not work. The problem that I am having is I dont know what name the user will be passing to me, so for dynamic purposes I chose a pointer, since a char array wasnt working out either.

Comment: you could always `char *str="hello\0\0\0\0\0\..."` (95 zeroes)

Comment: Show complete code that includes your call to `sys_open`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign strings that way in C.  You'll need to use [`strcpy(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/) or one of its relatives.

Comment: Well yeah, `*str = "Hello";` is a compiler error, but `str = "Hello";` is legal.

Comment: It's just a warning on my machine.  `incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [6]'`

Comment: I just wrote that to make a point. The actual problem that I am having is passing it as a parameter. I know that str has the string I want, since I do a printf right before it, but when I pass it sys_read, I get a negative fd, but when I use a char array, its all fine.

Comment: I pass sys_open(infileName, "0_RDWR", 00700); if I were to put a string literal lile "a.txt" instead of infileName, it would work. My pointer does not work. The problem that I am having is I dont know what name the user will be passing to me, so for dynamic purposes I chose a pointer, since a char array wasnt working out either.

Comment: Why do you have `O_RDWR` in quotes?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Except that it's *wrong* in the quotes.  The code you're showing just doesn't give me great confidence that you're fully explaining the problem.  Can you please show a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for us to help you more accurately?

Comment: Carl, using sys_open, I have a pointer that points argv[1], that pointer is named str. I am then passing str to sys open as a parameter. suppose argv[1] is "a.txt" when I pass str which points argv[1] it does not work. But if were to pass the literal a.txt to system call, it works I get what I want.

Comment: do I have to dereference str as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong:

```
*str = "Hello"; // or pass it any string
```

- `str` is `char*`, `*str` is a `char`, and `"Hello"` is a `const char*` (well, actually `const char[6]` that decays into `const char*`).  It's illegal to assign a `const char*` to a `char`.
- Assuming you meant `str = "Hello";`, that's still wrong because it's reassigning the pointer `str` to point to the string *literal* `"Hello"`.  The memory you previously allocated with `malloc` now has nothing pointing to it, and you've leaked memory.
- Passing `str` to `sys_read` as you're doing won't work.  `str` is pointing to a string literal not to the writable memory that you've allocated.  Not only will the `count` be wrong, but `sys_read` won't be able to write to it at all. (String literals are immutable, and attempting to modify one will result in undefined behavior.)

Comment: I am using a function, that copies argv[1] into str, and I have done a printf to ensure str has the right string in it.

Answer (score -2):

In the program, I feel that there is a type-cast missing as malloc returns a `void *` and assigning the same to `char *` gives an error.

Comment: Conversions to and from `void *` from other pointer types are implicit in C.

Comment: Isn't it dependent on the compiler? The aforementioned piece of code failed to compile on Visual studio without the typecast.

Comment: No it is not dependent on the compiler.  You must be using a C++ compiler.

Comment: what if pointer is already declared and later down the code I want to assign it. would it just be str = argv[1]?